# Every torrent I try to make with uTorrent gets stuck like this

Tags: utorrent

Every torrent I try to make with uTorrent gets stuck like this. And I've tried with another client as well. Help!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you sure it's stuck? It takes time to hash all files, if you add a huge directory.

Comment: When you get started to face this? Have you tried with older version of utorrent?

Comment: As I think there are a lots of bug with every new release of utorrent so I always keep old one with me to go back and check out for that. Going to post it as answer glad that its helped you.

Comment: Yeah, it got stuck in another place now. About 2 thirds. :(

Comment: Still stuck? I will recommend you to uninstall other bittorrent client using [revouninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/).

Comment: Yes, I always do a clean and complete uninstall with Revo. Best software for that. But the thing that it does the same thing with another client and with other versions, makes me wonder what could be from windows that could interfere with uTorrent.

Comment: Next time mention me with @ and follow my user name. I mean to said that just install only old version of utorrent not any other bittorrent client and see if it resolve the issue. Also you can restore your windows at good known restore point where utorrrent was working.

Comment: I have just created and saved a torrent of 400 mb with utorrent version 3.1.3 build 27120 successfully.

Comment: @avirk I did a clean uninstall of everything I have related to torrents. Downloaded a portable version and it gets stuck as in the screen. I'm out of ideas.. :(

Comment: @avirk: I think I found the problem: http://i.imgur.com/2KX5m.png   What do I do now?

Comment: Then unfortunately its the time to take a new HDD or SSD whatever you prefer and backup all your data using [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download)

Answer (score -1):

I was having the exact same problem as OP although my torrent was getting stuck around the 80% mark. There were no foreign characters, no hidden files, no Mac only files, etc.

The solution was moving the files to another hard drive and creating a new torrent from this new directory. I then set the new torrent's destination back to the original directory, forced a re-check, and it's seeding without errors.